# php comparing two tables and showing icon if fields match

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have set up a very simple mysqli/php shopping cart page that allows a user to click a button to "add to cart", which then inserts the product record into a different table, with a transaction ID controlled by a session variable to link all the products together in one customer's cart.

It works really well, and the customer can continue to shop the same list of products, but I want to know if there is any way I can cross reference each product with the info in the second table, so I can either hide that product that has been added to the cart, or add some sort of icon to show them they already added it.

Hope this is clear enough.

DATABASE QUERY "$DETAILS" Returns fields for page, and when button is clicked inserts into ITEM NAME and PRICE into another table

CODE -

```
<?php
while(!$DETAILS->atEnd()) {
?>
       <div class="row">
      <?php if ($DETAILS->getColumnVal("OTHER_IMAGES") != "") { 
        $colsize = "col-md-4"; } else { $colsize = "col-md-9"; } ?>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="input/images/<?php echo($DETAILS->getColumnVal("MAIN_IMAGE")); ?>" rel="dmxLightbox" rev="{group:'IMGS'}">
        <img src="input/images/<?php echo($DETAILS->getColumnVal("MAIN_IMAGE")); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo($DETAILS->getColumnVal("TITLE")); ?>"/> 
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="<?php echo $colsize; ?>"> 
            <h2><span style="color: yellow"><?php echo($DETAILS->getColumnVal("TITLE")); ?></span><br>
        <?php
            setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US.UTF-8');
            echo (money_format('%.2n', $DETAILS->getColumnVal("PRICE")));  ?></h2><br>
            <p style="color: white">Dimensions: <?php echo($DETAILS->getColumnVal("DIMENSIONS")); ?></p>
            <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cart_ID" value="<?php echo rand(111,999999); ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="cart_TITLE" value="<?php echo($DETAILS->getColumnVal("TITLE")); ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="cart_PRICE" value="<?php echo($DETAILS->getColumnVal("PRICE")); ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="cart_TRANS_ID" value="<?php echo($_SESSION['TRANS_ID']); ?>">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="ADD TO CART" name="cart_ADD">
            </form>



        </div>

          <?php if ($DETAILS->getColumnVal("OTHER_IMAGES") != "") { ?>            

<div class="col-md-5"> 
<div class="row">         
      <?php 
$someJSON = $DETAILS->getColumnVal("OTHER_IMAGES");

$someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);

foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
echo  
"<div class=\"col-md-4\" style=\"margin-bottom: 5px\">
<a href=\"input/" . $value["name"]. 
" \" rel=\"dmxLightbox\" rev=\"{group:'IMGS'}\"> <img class=\"img-   thumbnail\" src=\"input/" . $value["name"]. "\" class=\"img-responsive\"></a>   </div>";
}

?>
</div>
</div>          


 <?php   }  ?>





      </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php echo($DETAILS->getColumnVal("DESCRIPTION")); ?>
        <hr>
          </div>


      </div>

 <?php
 $DETAILS->moveNext();
}
$DETAILS->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
?>
```

Comment: Please share your table details

Comment: It may be very simple but we aren't magicians.. Show your code

Comment: @Mureinik Thanks for helping, I added the html code and the query details, hope that helps?

Comment: @Option My apologies. I have added it now, hope it helps.